# Problems Verifying Phone Number with Firebase (MFA)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I’m trying to verify a phone number with Firebase when enrolling for Multi-Factor Authentication. I have a simple HTML and JavaScript app where I want to enable MFA for an already logged in user. That is, the user is not enrolling in MFA at login—they are enrolling through their profile at a later time. I’m following the instructions here:

https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/web/mfa

I can initialize the RecapatchVerifier successfully (step 3) and create a multiFactorSession (step 4) and initialize PhoneInfoOptions (step 5). However, when I try to verify the number with a PhoneAuthProvider (step 6), it throws an "auth/internal-error". I think this is because I'm not passing the right phone options (see below). Is the phoneNumber property deprecated? I can't find any other documentation on this that doesn't require a resolver hint (“[s]ign the user in with their first factor, then catch the auth/multi-factor-auth-required error. This error contains a resolver, hints on the enrolled second factors, and an underlying session proving the user successfully authenticated with the first factor.”), which I can't use because there is no error, I'm enrolling for the first time.

```
function twoFactor(new_phone) {
            console.log("got the phone number, start enrolling in 2FA
");
            multiFactor(user)
                .getSession()
                .then((multiFactorSession) => {
                    console.log('1')
                    // Is this the right object to use when enrolling a new MFA?
                    const phoneInfoOptions = {
                        phoneNumber: new_phone,
                        session: multiFactorSession
                    }
                    const phoneProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth)
                    return phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneInfoOptions, recapatchaVerifier) //error happens on the return
                    // This promise creates an auth/internal-error
                }).then(verificationId => {
                    console.log('2')
                    const credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, window.prompt('Enter your code'))
                    const assertion = PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.assertion(credential)
                    return multiFactor(user).enroll(assertion)
                })
        }
```

Error:

[image]

edit:

After adding the .catch as shown:

```
function twoFactor(new_phone) {
        console.log('new_phone test:', new_phone)
        console.log('user test:', user)
        multiFactor(user)
            .getSession()
            .then((multiFactorSession) => {
                console.log('1')
                // Is this the right object to use when enrolling a new MFA?
                const phoneInfoOptions = {
                    phoneNumber: new_phone,
                    session: multiFactorSession  
                }
                console.log('phoneInfoOptions test:', phoneInfoOptions)
                console.log('auth test:', auth)
                const phoneProvider = new PhoneAuthProvider(auth)
                
                return phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(phoneInfoOptions, recapatchaVerifier)
                // This promise creates an auth/internal-error
            }).then(verificationId => {
                console.log('2')
                const credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId, window.prompt('Enter your code'))
                const assertion = PhoneMultiFactorGenerator.assertion(credential)
                return multiFactor(user).enroll(assertion)
            }).catch(err => console.log(err, err.message))
    }
```

[image]

Comment: According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/errors `auth/internal-error` means "The Authentication server encountered an unexpected error while trying to process the request. The error message should contain the response from the Authentication server containing additional information." Try adding a `.catch(err => console.log(error, error.message))` to log the message...

Comment: Sorry for the delay in getting back to you @AnisAbboud—see the update above. Doesn't give a very helpful error (at least to me). The user is properly logged in.